# Change NetworkManager connection file location

Tags: networking, networkmanager, profile

I'm trying to move the connection profile generated by the Network Manager from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` to another position and to be able to activate it among multiple sessions after a system reboot.
I changed the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file adding

```
[keyfile]
path=/mnt/NetworkManager/
```

At this point, when I create a new connection the profile file is correctly created in the specified path and the connection is activated without problem but if I reboot the system the NetworkManager seems to be not able to see this profile.

For completeness, my system is booted up with a read-only filesystem while `/mnt` is mounted with reading and writing permissions.

Comment: Is `/mnt/NetworkManager/` mounted at boot?

Comment: No. It is mounted by a custom python process that starts every process required by my application.